# How can I change NSWindow's title color in Swift OS X app?

Tags: macos, swift, colors, title, nswindow

I have tried lot of things, but nothing works...Also NSWindow won't accept NSAttributedString's. How to change color of window's title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution in Swift. It is late and I'm tired so this is probably not optimal but it works.

First, here is a function to find a view within an hierarchy, with the option to skip a specific view. (Which is useful if we are going search through `window.contentView.superview.subviews` and we want to ignore your  own views in the `contentView`)

```
func findViewInSubview(subviews: [NSView], #ignoreView: NSView, test: (NSView) -> Bool) -> NSView? {
    for v in subviews {
        if test(v) {
            return v
        } else if v != ignoreView {
            if let found = findViewInSubview(v.subviews as [NSView], ignoreView: ignoreView, test) {
                return found
            }
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

And here is how you would use it, for example from an `NSViewController` subclass. Note that you need to do it when the window has become visible, so you can't do it in `viewDidLoad`.

```
override func viewDidAppear() {
    if let windowContentView = view.window?.contentView as? NSView {
        if let windowContentSuperView = windowContentView.superview {
            let titleView = findViewInSubview(windowContentSuperView.subviews as [NSView], ignoreView: windowContentView) { (view) -> Bool in
                // We find the title by looking for an NSTextField. You may
                // want to make this test more strict and for example also
                // check for the title string value to be sure.
                return view is NSTextField
            }
            if let titleView = titleView as? NSTextField {
                titleView.attributedStringValue = NSAttributedString(string: "Hello", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: NSColor.redColor()])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*Do note that you are playing with fire. Internals like this are unspecified for a reason.*

Comment: findViewInSubview depreciated?